# comparing 2 arrays in every position

Tags: ruby

So what Im trying to accomplish is write a (shorter) condition that makes sure each element is different from the other array. This is confusing but I hope this example clears it up.

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
new_array = array.shuffle

until array[0] != new_array[0] &&
    array[1] != new_array[1] &&
    array[2] != new_array[2]

    new_array = array.shuffle
end
```

So what Im doing is making sure that every single element/index pair does not match in the other array.

```
# [1, 2, 3] => [3, 1, 2]   yayyyy
# [1, 2, 3] => [3, 2, 1] not what I want because the 2 didnt move
```

Is there a better way to do what I want to do? Ive looked up the .any? and .none? but I cant seem to figure out how to implement them. Thanks!

Comment: Can `array` contain duplicates?

Comment: How many total arrays are possible?

Comment: Assuming 2 arrays and no duplicates. Again this is just for me so I can improve on refactoring. Im just not content on how "mediocre" this looks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
array.zip(new_array).all? { |left, right| left != right }
```

Comment: just so i can understand the process here, the `zip` method is allowing me to access both arrays at the same time. then the `all?` is comparing each element of the array to its respective index in the other array.
Essentially this: `array.zip(new_array).all? { |el, new_el| el != new_el }`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches that do not involve repeated sampling until a valid sample is obtained:

**Sample from the population of valid permutations**

Construct the population from which you are sampling:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

population = array.permutation(array.size).reject do |a|
  a.zip(array).any? { |e,f| e==f }
end
  #=> [[2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 4, 1, 2],
  #    [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Then just choose one at random:

```
10.times { p population.sample }
  # [4, 3, 1, 2]
  # [3, 4, 1, 2]
  # [3, 4, 1, 2]
  # [4, 3, 1, 2]
  # [2, 1, 4, 3]
  # [2, 1, 4, 3]
  # [4, 1, 2, 3]
  # [2, 1, 4, 3]
  # [4, 3, 1, 2]
  # [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

**Sequentially sample for each position in the array**

```
def sample_no_match(array)
  a = array.each_index.to_a.shuffle
  last_ndx = a[-1]

  a.dup.map do |i|
    if a.size == 2 && a[-1] == last_ndx
      select = a[-1]
    else
      select = (a-[i]).sample
    end
    a.delete(select)
    array[select]
  end
end          

10.times.each { p sample_no_match(array) }
  # [2, 4, 3, 1]
  # [4, 3, 1, 2]
  # [2, 1, 3, 4]
  # [1, 3, 4, 2]
  # [1, 3, 2, 4]
  # [1, 3, 2, 4]
  # [1, 4, 3, 2]
  # [3, 4, 2, 1]
  # [1, 3, 4, 2]
  # [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

I have been unable to prove or disprove that the second method produces a random sample. We can, however, determine relative frequencies of outcomes:

```
n = 500_000
h = n.times.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |_,h| h[sample_no_match(array)] += 1 }
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = (h[k]/(n.to_f)).round(4) }
h #=> {[1, 2, 3, 4]=>0.0418, [2, 1, 3, 4]=>0.0414, [1, 4, 2, 3]=>0.0418,
  #    [3, 4, 2, 1]=>0.0417, [4, 3, 2, 1]=>0.0415, [3, 1, 4, 2]=>0.0419,
  #    [2, 3, 1, 4]=>0.0420, [4, 2, 3, 1]=>0.0417, [3, 2, 1, 4]=>0.0413,
  #    [4, 2, 1, 3]=>0.0417, [2, 1, 4, 3]=>0.0419, [1, 3, 2, 4]=>0.0415,
  #    [1, 2, 4, 3]=>0.0418, [1, 3, 4, 2]=>0.0417, [2, 4, 1, 3]=>0.0414,
  #    [3, 4, 1, 2]=>0.0412, [1, 4, 3, 2]=>0.0423, [4, 1, 3, 2]=>0.0411,
  #    [3, 2, 4, 1]=>0.0411, [2, 4, 3, 1]=>0.0418, [3, 1, 2, 4]=>0.0419,
  #    [4, 3, 1, 2]=>0.0412, [4, 1, 2, 3]=>0.0421, [2, 3, 4, 1]=>0.0421}
avg =  (h.values.reduce(:+)/h.size.to_f).round(4)
  #=> 0.0417 
mn, mx = h.values.minmax
  #=> [0.0411, 0.0423] 
([avg-mn,mx-avg].max/avg).round(6)
  #=> 0.014388
```

which means that the maximum deviation from the average was only 1.4% percent of the average.

This suggests that the second method is a reasonable way of producing pseudo-random samples.

Initially, the first line of this method was:

```
  a = array.each_index.to_a
```

By looking at the frequency distribution for outcomes, however, it was clear that that method did *not* produce a pseudo-random sample; hence, the need to shuffle `a`.

Comment: Nice, I was just looking at `Array#permutation` and thinking about the applications!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
until array.zip(new_array).reject{ |x, y| x == y }.size == array.size
  new_array = array.shuffle
end
```

Note, though, that it will break for arrays like `[1]` or `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`, where the number of instances of `1` exceeds half the size of the array. Recommend `Array#uniq` or similar, along with checking for arrays of sizes `0` or `1`, depending on how trustworthy your input is!